# PHP MYSQL Carriage returns

Tags: php

I have a script that is backing up a wordpress database, and it works great. However, I'm trying to restore it with php, and it always stops at the carriage returns, and errors out.
 Error:

> \n\nThis is a text example, chang' at line 1
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '\n\n

I've tried `nl2br`, `htmlspecialchars`,  `mysql_real_escape_string`, even `preg-replacing` them.

here's the code I'm using:

```
// Connect to MySQL server
mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password) or die('Error connecting to MySQL server: ' . mysql_error());
// Select database
mysql_select_db($mysql_database) or die('Error selecting MySQL database: ' . mysql_error());

// Temporary variable, used to store current query
$templine = '';
// Read in entire file
$lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
// Loop through each line
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    // Skip it if it's a comment
    if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')
        continue;

    // Add this line to the current segment
    $templine .= $line;
    // If it has a semicolon at the end, it's the end of the query
    if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';')
    {
        // Perform the query
        mysql_query($templine) or print(mysql_error() . '<br /><br />');
        // Reset temp variable to empty
        $templine = '';
       }
}
```

the `$filename` variable is an `.sql` file that is formatted correctly. In the database dump, I can see the **\n's**, and I'm pretty sure `wordpress` does some sort of `nl2br`, and replaces them with `<p>`'s, so they can be removed or the spacing on the site gets removed completely.

Comment: echo $templine before you run the query. unless $filename contains valid mysql you re not doing what i think you think you are doing

Comment: Please use mysqli or PDO as opposed to mysql.

Comment: echoing $templine shows valid mysql, and I see the \n's. the $filename is a .sql file that came from a dump right from phpmyadmin, so it must be valid.

Comment: can't be valid if your getting an error, so ...

Comment: `\n`'s might be interpreted as newlines by PHP. Did you try escaping the backward slashes?